# Two ListBoxes that the user selects for font type and size in a returned message

Tags: c#, button, fonts, listbox

I am very new and extremely confused as to how I can accomplish this project. The project requests us to create a form with two ListBoxes—one contains at least four font names and the other contains at least four font sizes. Let the first item in each list be the default selection if the user fails to make a selection. Allow only one selection per ListBox. This is where I am starting to have problems; I don't need to have what the user selects displayed in a message but the message reflecting what the font size and type were that the user selected. After the user clicks a button, display "Hello" in the selected font and size. I need help in getting the button to display the message in the desired font in a C# Windows Visual Studio 2010 form. I have just a basic code written to start me off which includes the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //populate listbox1
        listBox1.Items.Add("Arial");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Calibri");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Times New Roman");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Verdana");

        //populate listbox2
        listBox2.Items.Add("8");
        listBox2.Items.Add("10");
        listBox2.Items.Add("12");
        listBox2.Items.Add("14");

        this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        this.listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;         
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Since this is the beginning of this project, the font name and size that the user selects will eventually produce a message in that chosen font name and size. Now I'm trying to elicit a call from a button clicked that will display the message "Hello" in the user’s choice of font and font size. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ListBox.SelectedIndex` property to set the initial selection of the listboxes.  For example, you can add the following lines of code to explicitly select the first items in the listboxes after you add the event handlers:

```
this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler (this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);     
listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;   // <--- set default selection for listBox1

this.listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler (this.listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);     
listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;   // <--- set default selection for listBox2
```

By default, the `SelectedIndex` property of a `ListBox` is -1, which means there is no selection.

To answer your second question, to display 'Hello' in the selected font and size, I will assume that we can simply change the font of the textBox1 control.

First, make sure that textBox1 has some text; put this statement into the `Form1` constructor after the call to `InitializeComponent`:

```
textBox1.Text = "Hello!";
```

Then, modify the event handlers to change the typeface and size of the font:

```
private void UpdateFont()
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;  // selection not complete yet, so do nothing

    string typeface = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    float size = Convert.ToSingle(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());

    textBox1.Font = new Font(typeface, size);
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    UpdateFont();
}  

private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    UpdateFont();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped on the default values. I will repost an edited version with the next area I'm looking at.

Comment: @Rocky did u look at my answer? that should solve the other question you asked

Comment: @Rocky Why did you down vote and un-mark my solution as the asnwer?  I answered your original question; you've incorporated my answer into your question and are now asking a different question!

Comment: If I do that then doesn't that close this discussion?

Comment: @Rocky Typically you would ask another question.  What is it that you want to accomplish next?  Do you have a button on your form that you want to be clicked, or do you want the text of textBox1 to bein the selected font and size?

Comment: @Monroe I have a button on my form that (when clicked) I am trying to display the message "Hello" in a text box. This message needs to be in the font name and size that the user selects.

Comment: @MonroeThomas Should I create this post as another question or just keep editing as I work on it and find other areas that I need help with?

Comment: @rocky You should post new questions for each particular problem you are having.  But to point you in the right direction, I've edited my answer to address your second question.  Good luck; let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @MonroeThomas The following errors appear when I place the UpdateFont() method:
'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem' and no extension method 'SelectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)                         
There is also a second error message that reads that textbox2 does not exist. Shouldn't this read texbox1?

Comment: @Rocky Sorry, those should have been listBox1 and listBox2, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

to put the default value of your listboxes:

```
        listBox1.SelectedItem = "Arial";
        listBox2.SelectedItem = "8";
```

or a better "dynamic solution":

```
      listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
      listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

the following code will make the text font and size change, depending on what the user has selected in the listbox.

```
  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Font = new Font(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Font = new Font(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    }
```

edit:
you are getting an error because there's probably no text in your textbox.

```
TextBox1.Text ="this is some text";
```

add this to your form.

Comment: Playing with this idea for a few more minutes. Thanks

Comment: I tried using this and get a NullReferenceException error message because the Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: put this in the public form() method:
TextBox1.Text ="this is some text";

Comment: I have this in the form class
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Hello!"; 
        }